# Magento 2 - Get name or alias of indice ElasticSearch Product and Category

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Is there a way to know what is the name or alias of the index created in elastic search in a custom module?

For example when i execute command line bin/magento indexer:reindex Magento change the names indices:

> colecciones_local_orlcas_default_thesaurus_20230112_201128
> colecciones_local_orlcas_default_catalog_category_20230112_201126
> colecciones_local_orlcas_default_catalog_product_20230112_201117

I need to get the alias or name of indice product and indice category.

For some functions i use smile elasticsuite, but for specific new module i need custom query, because i need the indice name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried solve this with Darshan modi answer, but response was empty, hope the Darshan modi answer helps someone.

After a few tries. I managed to make a solution that works perfectly, creating a module, by injecting the IndexOperationInterface class, This class belongs to the Elasticsuite module of Smile, below the code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Indexer
{

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Api\Index\IndexOperationInterface;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
private $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Api\Index\IndexOperationInterface
 */
private $indexManager;

/**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param StoreManagerInterface        $storeManager                 Store manager.
     * @param IndexOperationInterface      $indexManager                 Search engine index manager.
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        IndexOperationInterface $indexManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->indexManager = $indexManager;
    }

/**
     * Retrieve Category/Product indexer name.
     * $indexName = 'catalog_category'/'catalog_product'
     */
    public function getIndexerName($indexName)
    {
        $defaultStore = $this->getDefaultStoreView();
        $index = $this->indexManager->getIndexByName($indexName, $defaultStore);

        return $index->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve default Store View
     *
     * @return \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface
     */
    private function getDefaultStoreView()
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getDefaultStoreView();
        if (null === $store) {
            // Occurs when current user does not have access to default website (due to AdminGWS ACLS on Magento EE).
            $store = current($this->storeManager->getWebsites())->getDefaultStore();
        }

        return $store;
    }
}
```

I hope this solution helps someone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, the name or alias of the Elasticsearch index for Products can be obtained by using the following code:

```
$productIndex = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Product::INDEXER_ID)->getName();
$productAlias = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Product::INDEXER_ID)->getIndexName();
```

Similarly, the name or alias of the Elasticsearch index for Categories can be obtained by using the following code:

```
$categoryIndex = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Category::INDEXER_ID)->getName();
$categoryAlias = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Category::INDEXER_ID)->getIndexName();
```

Note that these code snippets assume that you have injected the \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry class into your class using Dependency Injection.

Comment: i dont know why, but response is empty, this is my code `$this->indexerRegistry->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product::INDEXER_ID)->getName();` same with getIndexName(), could you help me?, I can't find anything in the documentation, i too use smile/elasticsuite extension, can this have any effect? Thanks!